# Cannot connect iSpy 6.5.8.0 to public cam

Tags: windows-7, ip-camera

I'm trying to connect iSpy to this cam: http://96.19.129.36 for testing purposes.
This is what I'm doing:

- Add -> IP Camera -> MJPEG URL

  - Username: (blank)
  - Password: (blank)
  - MJPEG URL: http://96.19.129.36
  - Decode Key: (blank)

I hit OK.

Then I disable Recording, Motion detecting and set the camera as Active, but I get no picture. If I open the link in a browser, I get the picture.

What am I doing wrong?
P.S.: I'm using Windows 7 with 2GB RAM.

Comment: I used the camera wizard, selected the Axis 1343, left the rest as the defaults.  It worked.  Here's the mjpg URL: http://96.19.129.36/mjpg/video.mjpg

Comment: Write that as an answer in case others come here for help you this task. Is this an Arizona boarder patrol cam or what.